# Could not find the main class x. Program will Exit

Tags: java, eclipse, manifest

I explore other threads on stackoverflow, I explore the web but couldn't find the solution...
so I am posting it here with full "hello world" example.
I am using Eclipse 3.6/jdk 1.6 I write a one class using swt and want to export it as runnable file.

Here is how I am trying to do it:

File->Export->Java->Jar ...in the following dialogs I select to create new  manifest and select my mainc class for entry point, export it and run it but get this error:

> Could not find the main class co.My. Program will Exit

Here is my Manifest.mf file, with two empty lines at the end:

> Manifest-Version: 1.0 
>     Main-Class: co.My

In class I have method:

```
public static void main(String args[])
```

And here is download link for whole "hello world" project.
http://www.mediafire.com/?wl6mixmpatpglwh

Comment: Check your jre installation, check the name of your java file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember good, there is in Eclipse also an option to create a Runnable Jar File.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[This will help to solve the problem](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=502171)